# Event dispatcher doesn't work for swiping videos in TikTok?

Tags: javascript, console

I want to automatically swipe tik-tok videos, so I tried this in Chrome console, but it doesn't work.

```
var event = new KeyboardEvent('keydown');
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Tiktok is most likely preventing untrusted keyboard events from triggering the scroll. If you run this code

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  console.log(e)
})
window.dispatchEvent(
    new KeyboardEvent('keydown',{
        //keycode and code for down arrow
        keyCode:40,
        code:'ArrowDown'
    })
)
```

You'll get a `KeyboardEvent` object logged that looks something like this

```
KeyboardEvent {isTrusted: false, key: "", code: "ArrowDown", location: 0, ctrlKey: false, …}
```

Im pretty sure that Tiktok's keypress/keydown listener ignores synthetic keypresses (prolly by checking event.isTrusted) and thus automatically scrolling by simulating the down arrow press is probably out of question. However, you could target the next button on page and click it.

```js
// this is the class name for the up and down button
let buttonSelector = '.up-and-down';
let buttons  = document.querySelectorAll(buttonSelector)
let prev, next = null;
// if theres one button, then its the next
if(buttons.length == 1)
  next = buttons[0]
//if not then the first button is prev, and the last next
else
  [prev, next] = buttons
//now click
next && next.click();
```